# CPU Usage always > 100% for an application that has 100 threads and each thread reads log files in real-time using Apache Tailer

Tags: java, unix

I have an application that reads log files in real-time. At any point it reads ~100 files. In my code there are 100 threads dedicated to each file to tail-listen the logs. I have deployed the application on a Unix Server with 4 cores, and I observe that the CPU usage is always > 100%. How should I reduce the CPU usage?

Comment: By reducing the number of threads to something a bit more reasonable?

Comment: Add the command used to check CPU usage please.

Comment: "At any point it reads ~100 files, in my code there are 100 threads dedicated to each file to tail-listen the logs." - 100 threads per file???

Comment: One thread reads one file, and in total there are hundred threads that read 100 files.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the OP didn't mean 100 threads per file, but rather 100 threads for 100 files.  Anywho there are three options: read fewer logs, output less into the logs, or add more cores to your box.

Comment: How have you implemented the listening? Do the threads idle?

Comment: The files that these threads listen to, are super busy. There are literally thousands of lines written into these log files every second.

Comment: Good, fast, or cheap. Pick two. ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar with a number of languages. Let me start by asking, what kind of parse algo are you using?

I bet your not using GREP.. Switch whatever algorithm whether it's string.find, apache.string.utils, etc. To GREP and report back your findings.

I think you will be pleasantly surprised.

*cheers*

Comment: I use regular expressions to match few patterns and extract the messages from the log files.

Comment: Are you using an immutable string type to perform the extraction?

Comment: Please use a mutable strings when possible.

Comment: I am using mutable strings.